# What is this "php blast extension"?

Tags: php, dkim, blast

I need to do php dkim keys generation and I wanted to use php-opendkim for this.
From this https://github.com/xdecock/php-opendkim
But I have an error with some ext-blast package:

> Problem 1
>       - The requested PHP extension ext-blast * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's blast extension.

What is this "php blast extension" and where can I find it?

Comment: I would like to link it, but it's behind a pay wall, thus I would consider linking it as spam (promoting a product), and therefore I will not link it. Google it. First result you find is what you need.

Comment: The blast was wrong and developer fixed this error. But question is actual, how can I use this solve in PHP context?
How can I generate dkim keys with this one? Or maybe other solution?

Comment: In the last comment, were you asking about how to use this package? That's something you should ask the maintainer of the package, or figure out on your own the hard way